# btrfs performance decrease with `mixed mode`

Tags: performance, btrfs

I'm a bit grumpy that 2GB of space is being reserved for metadata in a virgin `btrfs` filesystem (created on an 11GB partition).

I'm considering recreating it using "mixed mode". `man mkfs.btrfs` says:

> Normally the data and metadata block groups are isolated. The mixed
>              mode will remove the isolation and store both types in the same
>              block group type. This helps to utilize the free space regardless
>              of the purpose and is suitable for small devices. [...]
>
> The mixed mode may lead to degraded performance on larger filesystems,
>   but is otherwise usable, even on multiple devices.

1. Why would performance be degraded when using mixed mode?
2. Are there any figures to quantify this?
3. How would using an SSD vs rotational disk affect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `btrfs balance` and the amount of space allocated reduced.

```
sudo btrfs balance start -v -musage=0 /path
```

Answer (score 1):

`man mkfs.btrfs` [does answer](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/mkfs.btrfs) to this question (my text markup):

> *The recommended size* for the mixed mode is for filesystems *less than **1GiB***. The soft recommendation is to use it for filesystems smaller than 5GiB. *The mixed mode may lead to **degraded** performance on larger filesystems, but is otherwise usable, even on multiple devices.*

Comment: I did read that which prompted me to ask my three sub questions - none of which I feel you have answered.

Comment: ah, I see. Probably it was worth mentioning in the question itself.